# JFace TableViewer - Deselected rows reselect themselves automatically, with bonus asynchronous weirdness

Tags: java, asynchronous, swt, jface

I'm writing an eclipse RCP program that has a single-select JFace TableViewer in the GUI. Single select TableViewers don't have a default way of deselecting the selection, so I figured I'd add one by adding my own listener. The idea is to clear the selection if the user clicks on the already-selected row.

```
myTableViewer.addPostSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener(){
    private boolean inLoop = false;
    private StructuredSelection previousSelection = StructuredSelection.EMPTY;

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {

        //Needed because setting the selection causes the listener to be called again.
        if (inLoop) {
            inLoop = false;
            return;
        }

        StructuredSelection newSelection = (StructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
        if (newSelection.equals(previousSelection)) {                
            newSelection = StructuredSelection.EMPTY;
            inLoop = true;
            myTableViewer.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY);
        }
        previousSelection = newSelection;
    }
});
```

This unfortunately doesn't work. The selection is very briefly cleared, but about .2 seconds later the TableViewer automatically reselects the row that I just barely deselected!

It gets better. I debugged the JFace code a little to try and solve the issue. The TableViewer delegates its selection code to a StructuredViewer. If I put a breakpoint in StructuredViewer.setSelection(...), then all of a sudden my code works.

Apparently the PostSelectionChangedListener is poorly named and fires before the selection code is done running. My listener then races the StructuredViewer code, ends up changing the value too early, and then immediately gets overwritten.

Is there any way to avoid this? I'd really like to be able to deselect rows in the table viewer without having to add a clunky deselection button or keybinding. So far I've tried calling myTableViewer.getTable().setSelection(...), as well as packing the setSelection() call into a Display.asyncExec(...), but with no luck as yet. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just for the record: the behavior seems not to be caused by JFace. A [plain SWT `Table`](http://pastebin.com/M43pWB8S) reacts the same way (at least on Windows). Thus using SWT only wouldn't help.

Comment: If the goal is to let the user select (or unselect) one item out of several, you may work around the issue with a `CheckboxTableViewer`. With an appropriate `ICheckStateListener` you can limit the number of checked rows to one. BTW, are you aware that Ctrl+Click is the _native_ way to deselect a row?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Rüdiger. I know that Ctrl+Click is native, and it's great for multiple selections, but it feels somehow clumsy when working with single-selection tables. Still, adding a Ctrl+Click listener might be the way to go.

Comment: I agree that Ctrl+Click is unintuitive and most users probably won't know. There is no need to add a listener in application code, it is already provided by the underlying platform.